# Powershell Script using Invoke-SQL command,needed for SQL job, the SQL Server version of Powershell is somewhat crippled, is there a workaround?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-2.0, sql-job

Full Question: Have Powershell Script using Invoke SQL command, using snappins, I need them to be included in a SQL job, the SQL Server version of Powershell is somewhat crippled, does anyone know a workaround?

From what I have gathered, SQL Management Studio's version of powershell is underpowered, not allowing for the use of snappins, as such it does not recognize the cmdlets that I used in the script. I have tried running it in the job as a command line prompt rather than a Powershell script, which causes the code to work somewhat, however I check the history on the job and it says that invoke-sql is still not a recognized cmdlet. I speculate that because I am running the code on a remote server, with different credentials than my standard my profile with the snappins preloaded isn't being loaded, though this is somewhat doubtful.

Also, as I am a powershell rookie, any advice on better coding practices/streamlining my code would be much appreciated!

Code is as follows:

```
# define parameters
param
(
$file = "\\server\folder\file.ps1"
)

"invoke-sqlcmd -query """ | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"

# retrieve set of table objects
$path = invoke-sqlcmd -query "select TableName from table WITH (NoLock)" -database db -server server

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$so = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions

 $so.DriPrimaryKey = $false
 $so.Nocollation = $true
 $so.IncludeIfNotExists = $true
 $so.NoIdentities = $true
 $so.AnsiPadding = $false

# script each table
foreach ($table in $path)
{
#$holder = $table
$table =  get-item sqlserver:\sql\server\default\databases\database\tables\dbo.$($table.TableName)
$table.script($so) | out-file -append $file 
}


(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -notmatch "ANSI_NULLS"  | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1" 
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -notmatch " AS "| out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1" 
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -notmatch "Quoted_" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -replace "\) ON \[PRIMARY\].*", ")" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -replace "\[text\]", "[nvarchar](max)" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -replace " SPARSE ", "" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"
(get-content "\\server\folder\file.ps1") -replace "COLUMN_SET FOR ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS", "" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1"


""" -database database -server server" | out-file "\\server\folder\file.ps1" -append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the answer to my own question. Using this site: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1684 and
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1199

I figured out that he was able to do so using a SQL Server Agent Proxy, so I followed the yellow brick road, and basically I set up a proxy to my account and was able to use the external powershell through a feature. A note, you need to create a credential under the securities tab in object explorer prior to being able to select one when creating the proxy. Basically I ended up creating a proxy named powershell, using the powershell subsystem, and use my login info to create a credential. VOILA!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the snapins each time.  In your editor you likely already have them loaded from another script/tab/session.  In SQL Server you will need to add something like this to the beginning of the script:

```
IF ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
    {
        Add-PsSnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100
    }
IF ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name sqlservercmdletsnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
    {
        Add-PsSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100
    }
```

Comment: See the problem is that sql server doesn't allow for the use of snapins as such get-pssnapin and add-pssnapin aren't recognized as evidenced by the error:

Comment: A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'IF ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name sqlserverprovidersnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term 'Get-PSSnapin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.

Comment: @user - is this `SQL Server 2008 r2` or non-r2?

Comment: it is SQL server 2008 r2 for sure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the error you are trying to workaround - can you post that?

Have you tried this from a PowerShell prompt?

Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100

Comment: Yea, I have, it works fine at a powershell command prompt, the problem is that it doesn't work within SQL Managements Studios version of powershell, which doesn't allow snapins.